# C++ array to OpenCV cv::Mat, has zeros in between elements

Tags: c++, opencv

```
int a1[8]={5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int b1[8]={7,2,9,4,6,1,4,1};
cv::Mat cvIn_image_a(1,8,CV_8UC1,&a1); //cv::imread("minilogue.bmp",0); // Read an image from a directory
cv::Mat cvIn_image_b(1,8,CV_8UC1,&b1);//cv::imread("download.bmp",0); // Read an image from a directory
std::memcpy(cvIn_image_a.data, a1, 1*8*sizeof(int));
cout<<"cvIn_image_a:"<<cvIn_image_a<<endl;
cout<<"cvIn_image_b:"<<cvIn_image_b<<endl;
```

Then the cout value is

`cvIn_image_a:[5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

`cvIn_image_b:[7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

I am confused why this happens,

Answer (score 1):

an `int` contains 4 bytes, and you try to squeeze an array of it into a `uchar` Mat. instead, use a uchar buffer:

```
uchar a1[8]={5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
cv::Mat cvIn_image_a(1,8,CV_8UC1,&a1);
cout<<"cvIn_image_a:"<<cvIn_image_a<<endl;
```

same for `double` :

```
double a1[8]={5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
cv::Mat cvIn_image_a(1,8,CV_64FC1,&a1);
cout<<"cvIn_image_a:"<<cvIn_image_a<<endl;
```

also, beware of the `memcpy` ! if your Mat contains 8 bytes, you must not copy 8 ints

in short, you have to be absolutely strict with the underlying datatypes here !